# impossible to build a dynamic NSURL to put images in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, nsurl

I try to display dynamic image.
image I receive in my json stream is `"http / mySite.com / image.jpg"`

So I created a var imageURL: UIImageView! in my class and I have a method that I fulfill my scrollview, in this method I this piece of code that does not work and I do not know what I've forgotten:Here the error of this line: `URLWithString 'is unavailable: use object building' NSURL (string :)'`

```
var imageURL: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(picture)
```

Here is the full code

```
self.imageURL = UIImageView()
self.imageURL.frame.origin.y = 50
var picture = subJson["pagemap"]["cse_thumbnail"][0]["src"].stringValue
var imageURL: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(picture)
var imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL)!
var image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
self.imageURL.image = UIImage(image)
```

thanks

Comment: Just a quick note as well. The above code will block the main thread until the image is downloaded from the server. That is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what the error tells you to do.

Instead of: `var imageURL = NSURL.URLWithSting(picture)`

do: `var imageURL = NSURL(string: picture)`